# bash - How can I re-display selection menu after a selection is chosen and performed

Tags: bash, select

I am making a tool script for my theme with 2 functions: Check for update, reinstall theme

So here is the code for selection menu:

```
PS3='Choose an option: '
options=("Check for update" "Reinstall theme")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
     case $opt in
             "Check for update")
                       echo "Checking update"
                               ;;
             "Reinstall theme")
                       echo "Reinstalling"
                               ;;
                               *) echo invalid option;;
     esac
done
```

When running it appear like this

```
1) Check for update
2) Reinstall theme
Choose an option:
```

I type 1 and enter, the check for update command is performed

The problem is when it finished performing the script, it re-display "Choose an option:" not with the menu. So it can make users hard to choose without the menu (especially after a long script)

```
1) Check for update
2) Reinstall theme
Choose an option: 1
Checking update
Choose an option:
```

So how can I re-display the menu after an option is performed

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm guessing you really want something like this:

```
check_update () {
    echo "Checking update"
}

reinstall_theme () {
    echo "Reinstalling theme"
}

while true; do
    options=("Check for update" "Reinstall theme")

    echo "Choose an option:"
    select opt in "${options[@]}"; do
        case $REPLY in
            1) check_update; break ;;
            2) reinstall_theme; break ;;
            *) echo "What's that?" >&2
        esac
    done

    echo "Doing other things..."

    echo "Are we done?"
    select opt in "Yes" "No"; do
        case $REPLY in
            1) break 2 ;;
            2) break ;;
            *) echo "Look, it's a simple question..." >&2
        esac
    done
done
```

I've separated out the tasks into separate function to keep the first `case` statement smaller. I've also used `$REPLY` rather than the option string in the `case` statements since this is shorter and won't break if you decide to change them but forget to update them in both places. I'm also choosing to not touch `PS3` as that may affect later `select` calls in the script. If I wanted a different prompt, I would set it once in and leave it (maybe `PS3="Your choice: "`). This would give a script with multiple questions a more uniform feel.

I've added an outer loop that iterates over everything until the user is done. You need this loop to re-display the question in the first `select` statement.

I've added `break` to the `case` statements, otherwise there's no way to exit other than interrupting the script.

The purpose of a `select` is to get an answer to one question from the user, not really to be the main event-loop of a script (by itself). In general, a `select`-`case` should really only set a variable or call a function and then carry on.

A shorter version that incorporates a "Quit" option in the first `select`:

```
check_update () {
    echo "Checking update"
}

reinstall_theme () {
    echo "Reinstalling theme"
}

while true; do
    options=("Check for update" "Reinstall theme" "Quit")

    echo "Choose an option: "
    select opt in "${options[@]}"; do
        case $REPLY in
            1) check_update; break ;;
            2) reinstall_theme; break ;;
            3) break 2 ;;
            *) echo "What's that?" >&2
        esac
    done
done

echo "Bye bye!"
```

Comment: Using an outside infinite loop with break 2 is a good clean solution to menu redrawing. Putting the options assignment outside that loop and using PS3 is a small bit cleaner

Comment: Resetting REPLY to an empty value after the `esac` will have the desired effect and is much cleaner. See @kanlukasz answer.

Comment: @GerardvanHelden That depends on what the user means by "after a long script". I don't really see how their answer is any "cleaner" if a long sequence of commands is to be fitted into it. Also, as I wrote, the purpose of the `select` loop is to get a selection from the user, not to be the main event loop of the script.

Comment: It's debatable of course, but if it acts like a loop, why not use it as a loop?

Answer (score 3):

Your do loop is endless and your select statement is outside of it. The script executes the select statement once and then stays in the do loop checking for case $opt over and over. My recommendation would be to put break after your case statement like this:

```
esac
break
done
```

Then, if you really want the whole script to repeat itself over and over again, create another loop that encloses everything from the select statement to the done statement.

Comment: How can i do that? I want it to repeat endlessly until users want to quit (I will add quit option later)

Answer (score 3):

I use this trick:

```
options=("First option" "Second option" "Quit")
PS3="So what? "
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
        "First option")
            echo "First option"
            ;;
        "Second option")
            echo "Second option"    
            ;;
        "Quit")
            echo "We are done..."
            break
            ;;
        *) 
            PS3="" # this hides the prompt
            echo asdf | select foo in "${options[@]}"; do break; done # dummy select 
            PS3="So what? " # this displays the common prompt
            ;;
    esac
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by set the `REPLY` variable to be empty after `esac`.

##### Example with your code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

PS3="Choose an option: "
options=("Check for update" "Reinstall theme")
select opt in "${options[@]}" ; do
    case $opt in
        "Check for update")
            echo "Checking update"
        ;;
        "Reinstall theme")
            echo "Reinstalling"
        ;;
        *)
            echo "invalid option"
        ;;
    esac
    REPLY=
done
```

##### Another example ( simpler version to understand ):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

select animal in dog duck cat bird quit ; do
    case $animal in
        dog)  echo "i'm a dog!" ;;
        duck) echo "i'm a duck!" ;;
        cat)  echo "i'm a cat!" ;;
        bird) echo "i'm a bird!" ;;
        quit) echo "bye" ; break ;;
        *)    echo "unknown animal, please try again..." ;;
    esac
    REPLY=
done
```

For an explanation, see the [GNU bash documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html) about conditional constructs - select

Comment: This is actually the only clean and (arguably) correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check my method, I handled it via a simple `function` and a `for` loop

```
for((i=0;i<${#opt[@]};i++));do echo "$((i+1))) ${opt[$i]}";done
```

and this is my sample code :

```
msg="Choose an option:"
opt=("Check_for_update" "Reinstall_theme")

refresh_the_list(){
echo -e "\n$msg"
for((i=0;i<${#opt[@]};i++))
do
        echo "$((i+1))) ${opt[$i]}"
done
}
echo $msg
select i in ${opt[@]}
do
        case $i in
                        ${opt[0]})
                                echo "Checking update"
                                refresh_the_list;;
                        ${opt[1]})
                                echo "Reinstalling"
                                refresh_the_list;;
                        *)
                                echo "invalid option"
                                refresh_the_list;;
        esac
done
```